# Switch debouncing in software

Tags: switch-debouncing, debouncing

This is more of a C logic query, but since the underlying issue is hardware, I posted it here. The code snippet is from Mr.Jack Ganssle's page on debouncing.

I was reading this code snippet:

[image]

Suppose I embed the code in a 1ms timer ISR, what would be the debounce time? Is it a determinate value?

Comment: You mean 1 ms; mS is a different unit entirely.

Comment: debounce time varies with switch hardware and with how the switch is physically manipulated

Comment: Note that this code only de-bounces one edge, I usually de-bounce both edges. i.e.,  the switch must be *un-pressed* for multiple samples before another press is recognized.

Comment: As an aside, debounce times are typically 2ms, but it does depend on the switch itself.  If the switch is to be operated by a unman then a debounce in the tens of milliseconds quickly becomes noticeable.

Comment: Hi Mr,Mattman69, You mean the code only de-bounces the Pressed (hi 2 lo) transition ?

Comment: @EmbSysDev - Correct, it only de-bounces hi to low transitions. Since the de-bounce time is long, it should still work OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *if* statement is looking for this pattern:

0b 1111 0000 0000 0000

The previous statement forces 3 of the bits high, so you are checking for this pattern:

0b XXX1 0000 0000 0000

After each sample, the pattern is shifted one to the left.

So, you need 12 consecutive samples low (switch pressed), and the previous sample high (un-pressed).

There is a slight uncertainty due to the sampling, so the debounce range is 12 samples +/- 1 sample. So 12 ms +/- 1 ms.